# scheduling a task in r through task scheduler for a script to run monthly shows error

Tags: r

I am trying to schedule a r script to run monthly, however I receive the error below

> ```
> "ERROR: Invalid value for /D option."     "Type \"SCHTASKS /CREATE /?\" for usage."
> attr(,"status").
> ```

I tried creating task through task scheduler however it appears that this does not work when the schedule time is monthly. It works perfectly for other options such as daily and once.

```
library(taskscheduleR)
myscript <- system.file("extdata", "New_Plan_Monthly.R", package = "taskscheduleR")
cat(readLines(myscript), sep = "\n")

taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscriptMonthly", rscript = myscript,
                     schedule = "MONTHLY", starttime = "14:00", startdate = format(Sys.Date()+25, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are some solutions. Try it.

Solution - 1

```
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscriptMonthly", 
                     rscript = "ENTER FULL ADDRESS\\New_Plan_Monthly.R,
                     schedule = "MONTHLY", 
                     starttime = "14:00", 
                     startdate = format(Sys.Date()+25, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Solution - 2

Use R-Studio Add in to scheduled your task. This option works perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out here is a snippet of my code which seems similar to yours.

The error below is referring to day hence /D option
"ERROR: Invalid value for /D option."

"Type \"SCHTASKS /CREATE /?\" for usage."

Here is my code example:

```
myscript <- system.file("extdata", "Script.R", package = "taskscheduleR")
cat(readLines(myscript), sep = "\n")

taskscheduler_create(taskname = "Name_of_Task", rscript = myscript, schedule = 
"MONTHLY", starttime = "09:10",startdate = format(Sys.Date(), 
"%m/%d/%Y"),days="01", months = "MAY")
```

So it appears that you need to specify what day(numeric value) of the month you want to run this script. In this case I am running my script the first of may. I could have it run the first of every month by changing "months" to 'months = "*" '